# Record Selection Formula in subreport vb6.0

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports, subreport

I have a crystal report rpt1. I am using rpt1 as subreport of rpt2.
I have following selection formula in my rpt1

```
rpt1.RecordSelectionFormula = " {BANK.PRID}= " & PRID & " "
```

Here Bank is a tbale Name

It works fine when it(rpt1) is used as independent report but when it is used as subreport of rpt2. the formula does not work.
How can I apply selection formula in sub-report? i could not find enough help from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu should use `OpenSubReport` to access your subreport in main report. Try this.

```
rpt2.OpenSubreport("rpt1").RecordSelectionFormula="{BANK.PRID}=" & PRID & ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a main report parameter ?PRID that your code can set.
Change the design of the report to pass PRID as a subreport link. 
Allow the subreport link creation to filter the subreport based on the link.